# Anlible. How do I add a condition to a loop operation?

Tags: ansible, xml-parsing, ansible-awx

How can I get from this data only the value `("subclientName": "test") where "count" = 1`

`"subclientName": "start9pm"` should not be in the selection

```
{
  "countbackupsetName": {
    "results": [
      {
        "actions": {
          "xpath": "//subClientProperties[subClientEntity[@subclientName=\"test\"]]/vmContent/children",
          "namespaces": {},
          "state": "present"
        },
        "changed": false,
        "count": 2,
        "msg": "found 2 nodes",
        "invocation": {
          "module_args": {
            "path": "/var/lib/awx/projects/commv/parse/get_subclient2.xml",
            "xpath": "//subClientProperties[subClientEntity[@subclientName=\"test\"]]/vmContent/children",
            "count": true,
            "namespaces": {},
            "state": "present",
            "print_match": false,
            "pretty_print": false,
            "input_type": "yaml",
            "backup": false,
            "strip_cdata_tags": false,
            "insertbefore": false,
            "insertafter": false,
            "xmlstring": null,
            "value": null,
            "attribute": null,
            "add_children": null,
            "set_children": null,
            "content": null
          }
        },
        "failed": false,
        "item": {
          "appName": "Virtual Server",
          "backupsetName": "backupset-test",
          "clientName": "name05-vcagent",
          "displayName": "name05-VCAgent",
          "instanceName": "VC01",
          "subclientName": "test"
        },
        "ansible_loop_var": "item"
      },
      {
        "actions": {
          "xpath": "//subClientProperties[subClientEntity[@subclientName=\"start9pm\"]]/vmContent/children",
          "namespaces": {},
          "state": "present"
        },
        "changed": false,
        "count": 2,
        "msg": "found 2 nodes",
        "invocation": {
          "module_args": {
            "path": "/var/lib/awx/projects/commv/parse/get_subclient2.xml",
            "xpath": "//subClientProperties[subClientEntity[@subclientName=\"start9pm\"]]/vmContent/children",
            "count": true,
            "namespaces": {},
            "state": "present",
            "print_match": false,
            "pretty_print": false,
            "input_type": "yaml",
            "backup": false,
            "strip_cdata_tags": false,
            "insertbefore": false,
            "insertafter": false,
            "xmlstring": null,
            "value": null,
            "attribute": null,
            "add_children": null,
            "set_children": null,
            "content": null
          }
        },
        "failed": false,
        "item": {
          "appName": "Virtual Server",
          "backupsetName": "Test01",
          "clientName": "name05-vcagent",
          "displayName": "name05-VCAgent",
          "instanceName": "VC01",
          "subclientName": "start9pm"
        },
        "ansible_loop_var": "item"
      }
    ],
    "msg": "All items completed",
    "changed": false
  },
  "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
  "_ansible_no_log": false,
  "changed": false
}
```

This is how I managed to select everything, without the condition operation:

```
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item.subclientName }}"
    loop: "{{ countbackupsetName.results|map(attribute='item')|list }}"
```

result:

```
{
  "msg": "test",
  "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
  "_ansible_no_log": false,
  "changed": false,
  "item": {
    "appName": "Virtual Server",
    "backupsetName": "backupset-test",
    "clientName": "name05-vcagent",
    "displayName": "name05-VCAgent",
    "instanceName": "VC01",
    "subclientName": "test"
  },
  "ansible_loop_var": "item",
  "_ansible_item_label": {
    "appName": "Virtual Server",
    "backupsetName": "backupset-test",
    "clientName": "name05-vcagent",
    "displayName": "name05-VCAgent",
    "instanceName": "VC01",
    "subclientName": "test"
  }
}
```

This is how I get to the data I need, but the number of lines is always different.

I also don't need lines where count ":" 2 "

code:

```
  - name: Show value in countbackupsetName.results.0.count
    debug:
      var: countbackupsetName.results.0.count
  - debug:
      var: countbackupsetName.results.0.item.subclientName        

  - name: Show value in countbackupsetName.results.1.count
    debug:
      var: countbackupsetName.results.1.count
  - debug:
      var: countbackupsetName.results.1.item.subclientName
```

result:

```
TASK [Show value in countbackupsetName.results.0.count] ************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "countbackupsetName.results.0.count": "1"
}
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "countbackupsetName.results.0.item.subclientName": "test"
}
TASK [Show value in countbackupsetName.results.1.count] ************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "countbackupsetName.results.1.count": "2"
}
```

code:

```
      - name: debug jinja
        debug:
          msg: |
            [
            {% for p in countbackupsetName.results %}
            {% for o in countbackupsetName.results[p].item %}
            {
            "count": "{{ countbackupsetName.results[p].count }}",
            "key": "{{ o }}",
            "value": "{{ countbackupsetName.results[p].item[o] }}"
             },
            {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
            ]
```

result:

```
     line 112, column 9, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I've got properly what is desired output. But idea should be the same regardless: loop through results checking for condition and printing matching items. Here you go:

```
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      data: {
          "countbackupsetName": {
            "results": [
              {
                "actions": {
                  "xpath": "//subClientProperties[subClientEntity[@subclientName=\"test\"]]/vmContent/children",
                  "namespaces": {},
                  "state": "present"
                },
                "changed": false,
                "count": 2,
                "msg": "found 2 nodes",
                "invocation": {
                  "module_args": {
                    "path": "/var/lib/awx/projects/commv/parse/get_subclient2.xml",
                    "xpath": "//subClientProperties[subClientEntity[@subclientName=\"test\"]]/vmContent/children",
                    "count": true,
                    "namespaces": {},
                    "state": "present",
                    "print_match": false,
                    "pretty_print": false,
                    "input_type": "yaml",
                    "backup": false,
                    "strip_cdata_tags": false,
                    "insertbefore": false,
                    "insertafter": false,
                    "xmlstring": null,
                    "value": null,
                    "attribute": null,
                    "add_children": null,
                    "set_children": null,
                    "content": null
                  }
                },
                "failed": false,
                "item": {
                  "appName": "Virtual Server",
                  "backupsetName": "backupset-test",
                  "clientName": "name05-vcagent",
                  "displayName": "name05-VCAgent",
                  "instanceName": "VC01",
                  "subclientName": "test"
                },
                "ansible_loop_var": "item"
              },
              {
                "actions": {
                  "xpath": "//subClientProperties[subClientEntity[@subclientName=\"start9pm\"]]/vmContent/children",
                  "namespaces": {},
                  "state": "present"
                },
                "changed": false,
                "count": 2,
                "msg": "found 2 nodes",
                "invocation": {
                  "module_args": {
                    "path": "/var/lib/awx/projects/commv/parse/get_subclient2.xml",
                    "xpath": "//subClientProperties[subClientEntity[@subclientName=\"start9pm\"]]/vmContent/children",
                    "count": true,
                    "namespaces": {},
                    "state": "present",
                    "print_match": false,
                    "pretty_print": false,
                    "input_type": "yaml",
                    "backup": false,
                    "strip_cdata_tags": false,
                    "insertbefore": false,
                    "insertafter": false,
                    "xmlstring": null,
                    "value": null,
                    "attribute": null,
                    "add_children": null,
                    "set_children": null,
                    "content": null
                  }
                },
                "failed": false,
                "item": {
                  "appName": "Virtual Server",
                  "backupsetName": "Test01",
                  "clientName": "name05-vcagent",
                  "displayName": "name05-VCAgent",
                  "instanceName": "VC01",
                  "subclientName": "start9pm"
                },
                "ansible_loop_var": "item"
              }
            ],
            "msg": "All items completed",
            "changed": false
          },
          "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
          "_ansible_no_log": false,
          "changed": false
        }

  - debug:
      var: result
    # check for condition in result
    when: result['item']['subclientName'] == "test"
    # iterate over result list
    loop: "{{ data['countbackupsetName']['results'] }}"
    # set loop_var to not confuse ansible's "item" var with "item" key in data
    loop_control:
      loop_var: result
```

Answer (score 0):

> Was able to solve the problem using json_query!

code:

```
      - set_fact:
          add_filter: "{{ countbackupsetName|json_query(query2) }}"
        vars:
          query2: "results[?count==`1`].item.subclientName"
      - name: debug json_query(query2)
        debug:
          var: add_filter
```

result:

```
TASK [debug json_query(query2)] ************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "add_filter": [
        "test"
    ]
}
```

code:

```
      - set_fact:
          add_filter: "{{ count_add_hostname.results|json_query(_query) }}"
        vars:
          _query: "[].{subclientName: '[?count==`1`]'.item.subclientName, 
          backupsetName: '[?count==`1`]'.item.backupsetName}"
      - name: debug json_query(add_filter)
        debug:
          var: add_filter
```

I try to execute in a loop

result:

```
TASK [debug json_query(add_filter) var=add_filter] *****************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "add_filter": [
        {
            "backupsetName": null,
            "subclientName": null
        },
        {
            "backupsetName": null,
            "subclientName": null
        },
        {
            "backupsetName": null,
            "subclientName": null
        }
    ]
}
```

> is the empty result related to a conflict in the loop item and the dictionary name item ...